# Special characters on Jasper Report from Java Primefaces

Tags: java, jasper-reports, encode, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to print characters like this:

```
°µ± Ω≥≤Δα
```

I'm not having a problem with the first 3, but the second set of characters are not being printed when I compile and execute the report from Primefaces App.

Here's the code I'm using to print the report:

```
try {
    fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.responseReset();
    ec.setRequestCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""
            + "Report.pdf\"");// opens in same page
    ec.setResponseContentType("application/pdf");
    OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
    Connection jdbcConnection = datasource.getConnection();
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFile);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
            .compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
            jasperReport, parameterMap, jdbcConnection);
    //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output);
    JRPdfExporter pdf = new JRPdfExporter();
    pdf.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    pdf.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
    pdf.exportReport();
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    fc.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The report runs and print every character I need when testing from Jasper Studio. I think the main issue here is the encode of the PDF stream, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Are you using the Font Extensions?

Comment: No, Because is not a font problem. In Jasper Studio it works with the predefined font. @AlexK

Comment: It can be the font issue. And you should use the Font Extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer myself. I just use Dejavu Sans in the report and put a maven dependency to the basic jasper fonts and that was it.

```
<!-- Fonts for special characters -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

That's a fragment of my pom.xml

Thanks to the guys in the comments who made it posible.